# Determine individual terms of SymPy expression

Tags: python, sympy

For a project I am working on I have to select a specific term from an arbitrary SymPy expression. For this I am using `.args` which works fine if the expression consists of multiple distinct terms, but returns the individual coefficients in the term if only a single term is present. See the following example:

```
import sympy as sym

x, c0, c1 = sym.symbols('x c0 c1')

f0 = c0*x
f1 = c1*x**2
f2 = c0*x + c1*x**2

print(f0.args) # Output: (c0, x)    Desired: (c0*x)
print(f1.args) # Output: (c1, x**2) Desired: (c1*x**2)
print(f2.args) # Output: (c0*x, c1*x**2)
```

This method works as I would want it to for `f2`, where it returns `(c0*x, c1*x**2)`. For `f0` and `f1` however it returns the coefficients `c0, c1` and `x` separately. How would I go achieving the desired output where for the single term expressions the coefficients and `x` are also returned as a multiplicative expression?

Note that ideally I would want this method to work for any form of expression, with arbitrary dependencies on `x` and an arbitrary amount of coefficients.

Comment: You can use `Add.make_args(f0)` for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit goes to [Oscar Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71204136/determine-individual-terms-of-sympy-expression/71204360#comment125863750_71204136). Since I can't accept their comment as the answer I am reposting it here while also providing a concrete example.

"You can use `Add.make_args(f0)`"

This would then look like this:

```
import sympy as sym

x, c0, c1 = sym.symbols('x c0 c1')

f0 = c0*x
f1 = c1*x**2
f2 = c0*x + c1*x**2

print(sym.Add.make_args(f0))
print(sym.Add.make_args(f1))
print(sym.Add.make_args(f2))
```

Which would return:

```
(c0*x,)
(c1*x**2,)
(c0*x, c1*x**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `poly` to state the fact that you have polynomials:

```
import sympy as sym
from sympy import symbols, Poly


x, c0, c1 = sym.symbols('x c0 c1')

f0 = sym.poly(c0*x)
f1 = sym.poly(c1*x**2)
f2 = c0*x + c1*x**2

print(f0.args) # Output: (c0, x)    Desired: (c0*x)
print(f1.args) # Output: (c1, x**2) Desired: (c1*x**2)
print(f2.args) # Output: (c0*x, c1*x**2)
```

returns

```
(c0*x, x, c0)
(c1*x**2, x, c1)
(c0*x, c1*x**2)
```

to get the monimials, simply use

```
f0.args[0]
```

which gives

```
c0*x
```